# NSmutablearray is how to store in NSmutableDictionary objective c

Tags: ios

I am creating a `NSMutableDictionary` and store the many `NSDictionary` in `NSMutableDictionary`. Now I store `NSMutableDictionary` into the `NSUserDefaults` and then use this `NSUserDefaults` in other screen:

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSData *userData = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"cartdata"];
cartDataDictionary = (NSMutableDictionary*) [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:userData];
NSLog(@"%@",cartDataDictionary);
NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)cartDataDictionary.count);
NSEnumerator *enumerator = [cartDataDictionary keyEnumerator];
id key;


while (key = [enumerator nextObject]) {
  NSDictionary *list = [cartDataDictionary objectForKey:key];

  ViewMenu *View = [[ViewMenu alloc]init];
  View.ItemName = [list  objectForKey:@"Dish_name"];
  View.itemPrice = [list  valueForKey:@"Price"];
  View.itemQty = [list valueForKey:@"Qty"];
  View.itemImage = [list valueForKey:@"image"];
  View.stringId = [list valueForKey:@"id"];
  [items addObject:View];
}
```

Now all the data in the "items" `NSMutable` array in now this items array through create tableview and display value in tableview controller now want to delete some data from the items I use,

```
[self.items removeObjectAtIndex:button.tag];
```

but this statement is removes data from the items array but it is not feasible I want to delete data from the Main `NSMutableDictionary` and reload tableview data and display updated value.

Comment: save the key also in the View object and then later use `dict[self.items[button.tag].key] = nil`

Comment: ... and get an exception.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the example code given `[self.items removeObjectAtIndex:button.tag];` is trying to remove an element from the `items` array. If you want to remove the data from the main array, the one stored in the `cartDataDictionary` property (which I assume is being used as your data source?) you need to remove it from that.

```
[cartDataDictionary[<key>] removeObjectForKey:<other_key>];
[tableView reloadData];
```

You will need to find `other_key` by looking it up in the `items` array.

Now when the table view reloads, the datasource has been updated to the data that you want to display.